# Defining a word in php

Tags: php, html, cpu-word

I`m  a total newbie in php, so sorry for my simple question. Need to know step by step.

EXAMPLE : index.php

```
<html>

<header>
-including a file (/lang.php for example)
</header>

<body>

<div>
<a href="aboutus.php"> - word1 - </a> | <a href="contact.php"> - word2 - </a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

EXAMPLE : lang.php

```
word1 = ABOUT US
word2 = CONTACT
```

How to make this work the most simple way?

Comment: The "most simple" way is to just type `ABOUT US` and `CONTACT` in the right places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lang.php will be something like:

```
<?php
$word1 = "About us";
$word2 = "Contact";
?>
```

And in your other file you will have

```
<?php
include "lang.php";
?>

<div>
<a href="aboutus.php"> - <?php echo $word1; ?> - </a> | 
   <a href="contact.php"> - <?php echo $word2; ?> - </a>
</div>
```

Remember:

1. variable names in PHP always start with `$`
2. PHP code needs to be between `<?php` and `?>` tags (or `<?` and `?>` if your server is configured to accept short tags)
3. There is no `<header>` tag in HTML. Maybe you are thinking of `<head>`. Anyway, `include` statements do not necessarily need to be in there

Comment: Yeah, just woke up, can`t believe I wrote <header>! I`ll try this solution, but I think that`s what I`ve been looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: @nico there is, in fact, a [`<header>`](http://html5doctor.com/the-header-element/) tag in html.

Comment: @Gabi Purcaru: cool, I did not know, I still have to give a good look at HTML5. Thanks for pointing it out